# How can you exit and compile a .am file

Tags: vim, nasm

I am using terminal on mac.
I did 'vim hello_worldd.asm' and it created a place for me to write my code.

But I don't know how to exit and run it.
Is there a command to do so?

Comment: Quit and save the file (hit the escape key then type :wq) from vim.  Then run the assembler (probably `nasm hello_worldd.asm`)

Answer (score 2):

To exit Vim, hit the `ESC` key to go to normal mode and then type: `:wq` to exit and save changes.

For NASM, use:

`nasm -f elf file.asm` to compile it.

Then you must link it so you can use:

`ld -s -o outfile file.o`

Then run with: `./outfile`.

If you can't run `./outfile`. You probably have a permission issue. Which you can fix by using `chmod` doing: `chmod +x outfile`.

Comment: thank you, but when I do ./outfile, I get permission denied

Comment: This answer is incorrect. nasm will only compile (assume ELF) to an object . You'll have to link it with LD (or GCC) first.

Comment: can you elaborate please?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Is that better? Thanks for the catch.